# Magnetic insulation between the gap in cyclotron?

Tags: particle-physics, magnetic-fields

I was reading my book where they said that the particle gains speed when it goes from one dee to another and this is due to the electric field  between them. So I was wondering if there was any role of magnetic field at the gaps or is there magnetic insulation there ?

Comment: The large applied magnetic field keeps the ions moving in the spiral path through the cyclotron. Are you thinking there is another field to worry about?

Comment: made some mistakes with the question....now i edited it .can u reply again

Comment: There is no need for 'magnetic insulation'. You want the magnetic field from the main magnet to keep the particles in (near) circular motion in the plane of the Ds. The rf waveforms driving the electric fields is not making any magnetic fields to worry about.